# Swift 3.0とSwift2.3のファイル実行順序について

Tags: swift, xcode

今日、Swift2.3プロジェクトを３に自動コンバートをしました。

するとファイルの読み込み順序が大幅に変更されてしまいました。
Config.swiftというファイルを作成し、変数・定数を記述・読み込みをさせていました。

読み込み順序は下記の通りです。

▼Swift2.3
AppDelegate.swift->Config.swift->Gameboard.swift

▼Swift3
AppDelegate.swift->Gameboard.swift->Config.swift

なぜConfig.swiftが後から読み込まれるようになったのか理由がわかりません。
この情報に関して日本語・英語で検索しましたが、情報が見当たりません。

どなたかご存知の方がいらっしゃったらご教授よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そもそも「読み込み順序」と言うのが何を表しているのでしょうか？ソースファイルの名前が並んでいますからコンパイル順序のことなのでしょうか、それともそのソースファイルに記載されたクラスのクラスローティングの順序でしょうか。どちらにしろ、Swiftではその順序は規定されていないので特定の順序を期待してコーディングされていたのであれば、そのコーディングこそが誤りであった、と言うことになります。できれば、単純化したコードを作成して、あなたの言うところの「読み込み順序」が何を表しているのかお示しいただけるでしょうか。

Comment: 関数の実行順といえばいいでしょうか。Configファイルで設定した変数に値を代入する場合、事前に変数が宣言されている必要があります。しかしSwift３にしてからされていません。

Comment: コード例でお示しいただくことはできませんか。ご自身の質問は「編集」が可能ですから、コードを追記してくだされば何を言いたいのか理解できる可能性があると思っているのですが。Swiftコンパイラの可視性規則では、「事前」「事後」と言った観点は存在しないので、「事前に変数が宣言されている必要‌​があります」と言うのが何を言っているのかわからないのですが。